# Does it make sense for a Student class to have a static method getAllStudents()?

Tags: java, class, model-view-controller, static, dao

I'm practicing with MVC, DAO and other design patterns for a Java project.

Let's say I have a PageController that interacts with a Student class Model.

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public Student(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    //Getters and setters blabla
}
```

and then I have obviously a StudentDAO interface and StudentDAOImpl that executes SQL queries and stuff.

Let's say PageController needs to retrieve a list of all Students (to list them on its page), obviously I have an SQL query to retrieve a List of Students, implemented with a Java method in StudentDAOImpl.

Where should I instantiate studentDao (instance of StudentDAOImpl) though?
Can I simply create a static method in Student that retrieves all the Students? This static method would simply instantiate studentDAO and execute its getAllStudents method to retrieve all the students.

Or I can simply instantiate studentDao in PageController and do all the stuff from there?

Comment: Which way most effectively meets your specific needs?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't really know, none of these options really limits my possibillities, but I don't know how correct it is to just put a Dao instance inside a controller.  
Or to create a static method in Student that does getAllStudents(), I actually prefer this second approach because I can put all the Dao stuff in the Model part of my project.

Comment: "Correct" by what metric?

Comment: If you prefer the second approach, then use that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey with correct I mean "that follows MVC/DAO pattern" I guess

Comment: Follow [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dao-pattern) if you want to use the DAO pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In the main case, I think you could use [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dao-pattern)

DAO isn't a model, so you can add a method. I suppose that PageController would have a StudentRepository(StudentDAO) where will be a method getAll.

The structure mostly depends on the logic of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Adding getAllStudents (database access method) to the Student class is, in fact, related to a design pattern called [Active Record](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html)
Well, it's usually an anti-pattern for some people. Take a look at [this article](https://www.mehdi-khalili.com/orm-anti-patterns-part-1-active-record) for detailed explanation.

On the other hand, you mentioned that you are using a DAO, which is a different [design pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dao-pattern) for the same use case. I recommend you decide on a single option only.

If you are relying on DAO, everything related to data-access goes there. The model class must keep data only. However, be aware that this will lead you to an [Anemic Domain Model](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html), which has, in turn, its own drawbacks.

My preferred approach is [DDD](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DomainDrivenDesign.html), it balances the responsibility of the data-related classes in a more consistent way.

Regarding where instantiate your DAO, the rule of thumb is: don't do it. Use [Dependency Injection](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/injection002.htm) instead.
It's better because it leverages testability and maintainability of your code.

Comment: DDD doesn't have anything to do with these storage patterns, does it?  DDD doesn't have anything to say about how you persist your data; that's an implementation detail.

Comment: @RobertHarvey indeed, it's a detail about how to implement the repository. However, the question was about how to organize methods that retrieves data, and since it's a study, it would be worth at least mentioning a broader approach.